# Radius and vertices of a polygon circumscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry, pi, polygons

While searching to find a way to circumscribe a polygon in a circle of radius $1$, I found that the radius of this polygon should be $\frac{1}{cos(\pi /n)}$ where n is the number of sides.
However, I don't see why this is the case.

Furthermore, knowing that, how should I know the coordinates of the vertices?

Comment: By _found_ do you mean you located an unjustified formula somewhere...? <> Drawing a unit-altitude isosceles triangle with vertex angle $2\pi/n$ and calculating the side lengths should help. <> Have you encountered polar coordinates?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang
Yes, exactly I found an unjustified formula. I tried it on mathematica and it worked.

Comment: I understand that the radius of the inner polygon is $r cos(\pi /n)$, but I don't have the intuition about the circumscribe one.

Comment: Do you need a justification for some reason? If so, that might be a helpful detail to add to the question. (If this is homework, for example, it's not necessarily wrong to ask here, but knowing that might affect how and if people answer.) <> Again, drawing a unit-altitude isosceles triangle with vertex angle $2\pi/n$ and using trigonometry should has the benefit of allowing you to justify the formula yourself. :)

Comment: As for the coordinates, that is going to depend on how you orient your polygon with respect to the coordinate axes, and on where your unit circle is located.